# pyenv-win ignores local version

Tags: pyenv

I am having some trouble to use the actual Python version specified by `pyenv local`.

```
Z:\>pyenv global
3.10.6

Z:\>pyenv local
3.9.12

Z:\>pyenv which python
C:\xxx\yyy\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.12\python.exe

Z:\>python
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have another system version of Python installed. If so, check your PATH order in 'Environment Variables'. Make sure that the path to pyenv-win\shims is higher than another installed version.