# pyenv-win not overriding system Python version with local setting

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, pyenv, pyenv-win

I've installed `pyenv-win 3.1.1` on Windows using Chocolatey and successfully installed Python 2.6 using `pyenv install 2.6`. I then tried setting the local Python version for my project by navigating to the project directory and running `pyenv local 2.6`, which completed without errors.

When I check the versions with `pyenv versions`, I see:

```
* 2.6 (set by path\to\project\.python-version)
  3.8.10
```

indicating that Python 2.6 is correctly set as the local version for my project. Additionally, `pyenv which python` points to the expected Python executable at `C:\Users\<userName>\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\2.6\python.exe`.

However, when I run `python --version` in my project directory, it still points to my system Python installation (`Python 3.11.7` at `C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe`). Running `where python` yields:

```
C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe
C:\Users\<userName>\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python
C:\Users\<userName>\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python.bat
```

I expected that after running `pyenv local 2.6`, the `python` command would point to the Python 2.6 version installed via `pyenv-win`. Can anyone help me understand why `pyenv local 2.6` does not seem to override the system Python version as expected in this context?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74055928/4999991), I could find a temporary solution:

```bat
set PATH=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\;%PATH%
```

of course, if you want a permanent solution, then you have to manually add the above path to your environment variables. However, beware that it can cause some issues, and I do not recommend it.