# Error Installing `pip` on Python 2.6 with `get-pip.py`: ValueError for Format String

Tags: windows, pip, python-2.6

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78200737/4999991), I have successfully installed Python 2.6 on Windows using `pyenv-win` and set it as the local version for my project using `pyenv local 2.6`. When I check with `pyenv versions`, it confirms that Python 2.6 is the active version.

To install `pip`, I downloaded the `get-pip.py` script from the [official source](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). However, when I attempt to run the script using the command `python get-pip.py`, I encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 29, in <module>
    "This script does not work on Python {}.{}".format(*this_python),
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

This error suggests a compatibility issue with the formatting string in Python 2.6, which requires explicit positional indices for format fields.

I know Python 2.6 is quite old and might not be directly supported by the latest `get-pip.py` script, but I need `pip` to manage packages for a [legacy project](https://github.com/JModelica/JModelica/tree/master/external/Assimulo).

Has anyone encountered and resolved this issue, or can anyone suggest a workaround for installing `pip` on Python 2.6?

**P.S.** I voted to close the question because I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77609580/4999991) already resolves my problem, even though the error message is different.